# Snowflake not accepting aliases in joins

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This one is pretty weird to me. I have some scheduled jobs that have been working, verifiably and correctly, for months and months. But they appeared to have broken 3 days ago.

```
SELECT
    id as id,
    ltrim(split_part(hosts._FILE, '/', 6), 's') as uuid,
    split_part(hosts._FILE, '/', 5) as device_server,
    CAST(devicetype AS int) as devicetype,
    recycled_on AS recently_deleted,
    replace(split_part(hosts._FILE, '/', -1), '.csv') as time_raw,
    TO_CHAR(
      DATE_TRUNC('day',
        CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles',
          CAST(replace(split_part(hosts._FILE, '/', -1), '.csv') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
      )),
      'YYYY-MM-DD') as snapshot_date,
    TO_CHAR(
      DATE_TRUNC('hour',
        CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', 
          CAST(replace(split_part(hosts._FILE, '/', -1), '.csv')   AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
      )),
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') as snapshot_hour
FROM Santaba.hosts_new as hosts
INNER JOIN usage_hosts_daily
      ON usage_hosts_daily.suuid = uuid
      AND usage_hosts_daily.sdevice_server = device_server
      AND usage_hosts_daily.ssnapshot_hour = snapshot_hour
WHERE hosts.recycled_on = 0
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

The break is on this line:
`ON usage_hosts_daily.suuid = uuid`
along with the rest of the joins. Where I get this error:

`SQL compilation error: error line 22 at position 39 invalid identifier 'UUID'`

Normally I would just specify the TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN_ALIAS but even that causes the error and the only thing that has worked is just to put the entire SELECT argument for that column as the other part of the join.

I haven't seen any updates from Snowflake as to why this might have happened. Anyone have a better idea as to the cause of this?

Comment: Our support engineer is currently arranging the parameter reversion for our account. Much better than having to refactor several dozen queries!

Comment: do you know what parameter was revised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have been caused by an update from Snowflake. Please reach out to support to get this fixed.

Comment: yes, this is caused by a parameter fix I believe which went in recently. Support can flip it.

Comment: (Sorry - the comment above refers to this comment) Has this ever worked with Snowflake? I know Teradata has some support for this but I think eg. Oracle hasn't... Not even GROUP BY aliasing

Comment: I am contacting them but I can confirm that this query and ones like it have worked for months and months. Until 3 days ago it always allowed for queries like this.

@AbhiReddy do you know where release notes on these parameter changes might be?

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/3-50-Release-Notes-November-4-2019 

This doesn't seem to contain any info on it specifically.

Comment: sorry, I can't find any either, support can fill in the details on this one.

Comment: do you know what parameter was revised? @AbhiReddy

Answer (score 3):

Our Sales Engineer was able to get a priority ticket for our Snowflake instance and revert the parameter fix to a previous version.

That being said, I am curious what kind of parameter fix was implemented that would fundamentally change such basic SQL statements.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by the recent parameter change. You can reach out to the Snowflake support to have the parameter set for your account to make this work.